# Grandparent Entity Class saving child data in JPA

Tags: hibernate, entity-framework, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 level of Entity class.
In this Case I have added cascade.All for GranParent Class A. So when I am saving A it is saving B and C also
My requirement is C is a static data table and And I dont want to save any data there.
Now I am getting error because it is trying to save into C.

```
Class A{
       @OneToMany(cascade.=Cascade.ALL, mappedBy="id")
       private List<B> b;
```

}

```
Class B{

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinCloumn(name="cId")
  private C c;
```

}

Comment: You will need to provide more detail about how you are trying to save your data, because C would only change for two reasons, either you made tracked changes to it, or you are using an untracked instance where you should be referencing a tracked one.

Comment: I am saving data using JPA repository. ARepository.save(). So it is internally trying to save all the child Entity.